# What are the essentials of the Faith?

Tags: faith, doctrine

Please list the essential points of the Gospel. Please use Bible quotations to back up your answers.

A short list I've been pondering:

1. God's Character and Nature
2. Our brokenness from the Fall
3. Christ sent as Redeemer

   a. Crucifixion

   b. Resurrection
4. How we should respond to Christ's Atoning Sacrifice.

Just thinking in terms of what is essential.

Comment: > If you declare with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. (Rom 10:9)

This suggests that the essentials are: Lordship of Christ, and the Resurrection.

Maybe other verses elaborate. St. Paul's Mars Hill sermon gives some background that may be needed to *understand* the need for Christ.

Comment: @ Rich - Important question.  However would the question be improved by editing so as to ask, "What essentials of the Faith should every **Seeker**  be taught before  accepting...etc." Keep studying the Bible: it's great for the soul!

Comment: @Maverick I would add to your comments the groundwork (see the parable of the sower) of the baptism of repentance (see also John the Baptist and also the water to wine at Cana) as also expressed throughout the penitential psalms.

Answer (score 3):

Acts 2:38: "Repent and be baptized."

Rom 10:9: "Declare with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead."

Matt 7:21: "Only the one who does the will of my Father."

Acts 16:30-33: "Believe in the Lord Jesus."

John 20:30-31: "That you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that believing you may have life in His name.”

For the belief component, I would sum this up as: Lordship of Christ; Christ as Son of God; Resurrection. But of course it's the scripture, not any one man's summary, that matters.

Comment: Up-voted +1. I would add to your comments the groundwork (see the parable of the sower) of the baptism of repentance (see also John the Baptist and also the water to wine at Cana) as also expressed throughout the penitential psalms

Answer (score 0):

Mere belief is irrelevant. How can one be a Christian without being anointed? Without having received the Spirit?

Rebirth is the most crucial part; without being born again/from above/of God through water and Spirit, no one will be saved.

You can believe the wonderful things in the OP all your life, and once you have died you'll burn for all eternity (while being fully conscious).

Satan is very pleased with churchy folk who refuse to be regenerated through water & Spirit immersion because they could as well spit on the Messiah's sacrifice. And if one doesn't warn others that they must undergo spiritual rebirth in this life in order to be saved, one could as well kick them right now into the lake of fire. And the gently smiling Christ-like believers who tell others that they are born again and saved because they have "accepted Jesus as Lord and Saviour" will burn in the lowest and likely hottest regions of Gehinnom.